# I am trying to practice new and delete functions, but my code 'Triggers a breakpoint'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, breakpoints, new-operator

When I try to run my code, which should return the factorial of a number, it triggers a breakpoint according to visual studio. I know there are better ways to do it but I want to practice the use of pointers, and the new and delete functions.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* p1;
    int num, factorial = 1;
    cout << "Write the number: ";
    cin >> num;
    p1 = new int[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        p1 = p1 + i;
        *p1 = i + 1;
        factorial *= (*p1);
    }
    cout << "The factorial is: " << factorial << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to do it again? ";
    char yn;
    cin >> yn;
    while (yn == 'y')
    {
        factorial=1;
        delete[] p1;
        cout << "Write the number: ";
        cin >> num;
        p1 = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            p1 = p1 + i;
            *p1 = i + 1;
            factorial *= (*p1);
        }
        cout << "The factorial is: " << factorial<<endl;
        cout << "Do you want to do it again? ";
        cin >> yn;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate an explanation more than another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this part of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    p1 = p1 + i; // <--- Here
```

Here, I believe that your intent was to say "make `p1` point `i` steps past the start of the array it points to." However, what you've written here doesn't do that. Specifically:

- On the first iteration, it's 0 steps past where it started.
- On the second iteration, it's 0 + 1 = 1 steps past where it started.
- On the third iteration, it's 0 + 1 + 2 = 3 steps past where it started.
- On the fourth iteration, it's 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 steps past where it started.

Eventually, this will overshoot the end of your array, which might be the immediate cause of your crash.

To fix this, instead of jumping the pointer forward, consider using array indexing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    p1[i] = i + 1;
    factorial *= p1[i];
}
```

Or, if you do want to use pointers, make a separate pointer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    int* p2 = p1 + i;
    *p2 = i + 1;
    factorial *= (*p2);
}
```

Hope this helps!